# Tabbar's viewcontroller gets reload while changing the orientation, in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I have a `UITabBarController` which has few tabs. When I change orientation of the app, in iOS 8, All of it's viewController's `viewDidLoad` get called. This is not happening when I run the app in iOS 7.

Is it any new functionality of iOS 8 that reload `UITabBarController` on orientation change?
If so How can I prevent my Tabbar to reload it's view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parul Garg is correct and I experienced the same issue.

Please be aware that you will need to call your orientation change methods manually once you enable `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

Each orientation change method call, calls this method and the method in the tabbar class.

The solution is to use manual calls, as follows:

```
-(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)sizewithTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
 //[super viewWillTransitionToSize:sizewithTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
   UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
   UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = orientation;    
   if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController;
        UIViewController* NavSubController = [[navCtrl viewControllers] lastObject];
        [NavSubController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:0.0];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I noticed that on iOS8 when the orientation of the device is changing viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: is getting called on UITabBarController, and UITabBarController calls viewDidLoad method of any viewcontroller that has not been loaded yet.

For now,in my UITabBarController subclass I override this method to not call [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator].

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    //Do not call [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    NSLog(@"Device orinetation changed");
}
```